# What if an Array of object's have a method that is static

Tags: java

I have an array of objects named `Employee[] emp = new Employee[5];`
and Employee have a static method inside e.g. `public static void myNum();`
how can I call this in each array subscripts `emp[0]` through `emp[5]`

Comment: Static methods don't need an instance of the object to be called, you can just use `Employee.myNum();`. However, are you asking how to write a `for` loop?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  Please post some code, and if there are parts that you don't know how to write, include a comment explaining exactly what you're trying to do, or else include pseudo-code that explains it.

Comment: A static method is called through it's class, in your case Employee.myNum() and its independent from any object of this class.

Comment: I'm making an array of Employee class how can I use the static method of emp[0] array element through emp[5]

Comment: 4castle answered this.  The whole point of a static method is that you DON'T call the method with an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally call a static method on an object instance. Something like:

```
emp[0].myNum();
```

It is considered bad form and will usually generate a compiler warning. But it will compile and you can do it if you like.

Comment: yes thanks I've also found in a book that static method can also be use with an object

Comment: @jobethbillien Please note that if you do this, the object you use will be _totally ignored_.  Using `emp[0].myNum()`, `emp[1].myNum()`, etc., will all do exactly the same thing, and it won't even look at the `emp[0]` or whatever.  If you want something that actually does behave differently for the different array elements, then please follow my earlier suggestion and post some code so that we know what you're trying to do.